# SQL Error: ORA-12899: value too large for column "SYSDBA"."MOVIES"."MOVIE_CATEGORY" (actual: 5, maximum: 1)

Tags: sql, oracle

Working on building a datebase, can't figure out what is wrong with my syntax, any help with an explanation is appreciated, when I try the syntax

```
select *
from movies;
```

It will display 44 rows, when there are only 13, and aliens will get displayed several times at some point.

> SQL Error: ORA-12899: value too large for column
>   "SYSDBA"."MOVIES"."MOVIE_CATEGORY" (actual: 5, maximum: 1)

here is my syntax

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIES
(MovieID NUMBER(2), 
Movietitle VARCHAR(50),
Movievalue NUMBER(2),
Moviequantity NUMBER(2),
categoryID NUMBER (1),
MovieCategory VARCHAR (20));




INSERT INTO MOVIES
VALUES (1,'Alien',10,5,1,'SciFi'); 
INSERT INTO MOVIES 
VALUES (2,'Bladerunner',8,3,1,'SciFi'); 
INSERT INTO MOVIES 
VALUES (3,'Star Wars',15,11,1,'SciFi');
INSERT INTO MOVIES 
VALUES (4,'Texas Chainsaw Masacre',7,2,2,'Horror'); 
INSERT INTO MOVIES 
VALUES (5,'JAWS',7,1,2,'Horror');
INSERT INTO MOVIES 
VALUES (6,'The good, the bad, and the ugly',7,2,3,'Western');
INSERT INTO MOVIES 
VALUES (7,'Silverado',7,1,3,'Western');
INSERT INTO MOVIES 
VALUES (8,'Duck Soup',5,1,4,'Comedy');
INSERT INTO MOVIES 
VALUES (9,'Planes, trains, and automobiles',5,3,4,'Comedy');
INSERT INTO MOVIES 
VALUES (10,'Walking Ned Devine',12,4,4,'Comedy');
INSERT INTO MOVIES 
VALUES (11,'Deep Blue Sea',14,3,5, 'Drama');
INSERT INTO MOVIES 
VALUES (12,'The Fifth Element',15,5,5,'Drama');
```

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b8bc/1

Comment: The error message talks about a 1 char long MOVIE_CATEGORY. Your sample code does not create or use it. Check what you use - but anyway the answer is, do not write 5 digits into columns which can only hold one. (and you really should specify column ames for `insert into`.

Comment: Did you actually create a schema named `SYSDBA`?  I'm not sure that's actually possible but it's almost certainly a terrible idea.

Comment: Following up on @eckes comment: the error message shows that the column's name is `MOVIE_CATEGORY`, but what the script you've included would create is `MOVIECATEGORY`, without the `_`; thus, I must conclude that the script you've shown did not create the table. I suggest that you run the following query and see how long the `MOVIE_CATEGORY` column is defined to be: `SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MOVIES'`. Best of luck.

Comment: Also, SELECT * FROM with no filters will return all the data in the table.  If the result set gives you 44 rows that's how many rows are in the table.  Your table doesn't appear to have a primary key or unique constraint, so the chances are you've just run the INSERT statements several times.